# Access $this inside a route in doesn't work "Using $this when not in object context"

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I'm trying to use `$this` inside a function of a route, when I'm doing this, it gives me the following error:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Here's the code:

```
function api($request, $response) {
    $response->write('REST API v1');
    $this->logger->addInfo("Something interesting happened"); 
    return $response;
}

$app = new \Slim\App();

/** my routes here **/
$app->get('/', 'api');

$app->run();
```

I have tried to implement it based on [this](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html).

Why it doesn't work to use `$this` inside the function and how can I use `$this` inside a function.

Comment: where do you use `$this->..`?

Comment: In all my route functions

Comment: add an example to your question

Comment: @jmattheis OP updated with example route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use `$this` inside the function when declaring it with a string. Use an anonymous function instead (a controller-class would also be a fix):

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
    $response->write('REST API v1');
    $this->logger->addInfo("Something interesting happened"); 
    return $response;
});
```

See: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html

> If you use a Closure instance as the route callback, the closure’s state is bound to the Container instance. This means you will have access to the DI container instance inside of the Closure via the `$this` keyword.