# Can't access token stored in container

Tags: jwt, slim

I followed the instructions to save token in container with callback function (https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth):

```
$app = new \Slim\App();

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container["jwt"] = function ($container) {
    return new StdClass;
};

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => ["/"],
    "passthrough" => ["/version", "/auth"],
    "secret" => "mysecret",
    "callback" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) use ($container) {
        $container["jwt"] = $arguments["decoded"];
    },
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));
```

No data is returned in response, it seems $this->jwt is empty.

```
$app->get("/user", 'getUsers');

function getUsers($req, $res, $args) {
    $decode = $this->jwt;
    print_r($decode);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access $this inside a route in slim3 doesn't work "Using $this when not in object context"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362978/access-this-inside-a-route-in-slim3-doesnt-work-using-this-when-not-in-objec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route definition throws `Using $this when not in object context` error. To have access to `$this` you need to use a closure  instead. See [closure binding](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html) in the documentation.

```
$app->get("/user", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    $decode = $this->jwt;
    print_r($decode);
});
```

or

```
$getUsers = function ($request, $response, $arguments) use ($container) {
    $decode = $this->jwt;
    print_r($decode);
};

$app->get("/user", $getUsers);
```

With the either of code above you can access decoded token via `$this`. First example is preferred.

```
$ curl --include http://localhost:8081/user --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.mHEOMTUPhzNDAKheszd1A74EyLmKgy3PFdmKLg4ZNAE"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8081
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.12
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 84

stdClass Object
(
    [sub] => 1234567890
    [name] => John Doe
    [admin] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The instruction you linked to states:

> Callback is called only when authentication succeeds. It receives
>   decoded token in arguments. If callback returns boolean `false`
>   authentication is forced to be failed.

Do you meet this requirement when testing, i.e do you authenticate successfully? Also consider using `var_dump($decode)` instead of `print_r($decode)` when testing.

Comment: Thanks! The token is received correcty, I did not passthrough this route.